# MySql Syntax Error in TRIGGER : What is the error in my trigger code?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a basic trigger syntax error. I am a beginner in mysql. Please help me.
I am having two tables.

Table 1 -

```
MariaDB [lab5]> create table library_2
 -> (id int AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
 -> Book_name varchar(20),
 -> Details varchar(50));
```

Table 2 -

```
MariaDB [lab5]> create table library_audit2
 -> (id int AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
 -> Book_Name varchar(20) not null,
 -> Details varchar(50) default null,
 -> change_date date,
 -> library_id int,
 -> foreign key(library_id) REFERENCES library_2(id));
```

Trigger -

```
MariaDB [lab5]> DELIMITER $$
MariaDB [lab5]> create trigger BeforeLibraryDelete
 -> BEFORE DELETE
 -> ON library_2 FOR EACH ROW
 -> BEGIN
 -> delete from library_audit2 lib where lib.library_id=OLD.id;
 -> END $$
```

The error -

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'lib where lib.library_id = :old.id;
END' at line 5
```

What is the error at line 5 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your delete needs to specify the table to delete from:

```
delete lib
-------^ the table alias goes between the `delete` and the `from`
    from library_audit2 lib
    where lib.library_id = OLD.id;
```